Wireguard no internet access on peer with MacOS Server
I have an older Macbook Pro lying around, so I thought I could turn it into a DIY home server. I'm struggling to get wireguard running on it as a server. The problem is the classic able to have the handshake succeed but no internet access on the peer that connects to the server.
My config files are shared below, my goal is to route all traffic from my Peers to the en0 interface on my server. I've tried to fiddle with the DNS and see that my resolv.conf is correctly populated.
❯ ifconfig en0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 12:7d:26:80:dd:ee
    inet 192.168.1.170 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active

❯ cat  /usr/local/etc/wireguard/postup.sh
#!/bin/sh

# 1) This ensures our peers continue to report their Wireguard
#    assigned IPs while connected to the VPN. This is required
#    for their traffic to get routed correctly by the firewall
#    rules we crafted earlier with pf.
/usr/sbin/sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

# 2) Preparing the directory where we'll persist the pf tokens
#    generated by Step (3) & (4). That token can then be used by
#    our postdown.sh script to remove the routing rules when
#    Wireguard is shut down.
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/run/wireguard
chmod 700 /usr/local/var/run/wireguard

# 3) Dynamically add the IPv4 NAT rule, enable the firewall,
#    increase its reference count (-E), and persist the reference
#    token generated by the command into
#    pf_wireguard_token_ipv4_token.txt, which postdown.sh will
#    reference when Wireguard is shut down.
echo 'nat on en0 from 10.0.10.1/24 to any -> (en0)' | \
        pfctl -a com.apple/wireguard_ipv4 -Ef - 2>&1 | \
        grep 'Token' | \
        sed 's%Token : \(.*\)%\1%' > /usr/local/var/run/wireguard/pf_wireguard_ipv4_token.txt
IPV4_TOKEN=`sudo cat /usr/local/var/run/wireguard/pf_wireguard_ipv4_token.txt`
echo "Added PF IPv4 NAT traffic routing rule with token: ${IPV4_TOKEN}"

❯ cat /usr/local/etc/wireguard/coordinates.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.10.1/24
ListenPort = 61820
PrivateKey = <redacted>
SaveConfig = false
MTU = 1280
#DNS = 1.1.1.1
PostUp = /usr/local/etc/wireguard/postup.sh
PostDown = /usr/local/etc/wireguard/postdown.sh

# 11: 11 > wgclient_11.conf
[Peer]
PublicKey = <redacted>
PresharedKey = <redacted>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.10.2

The output of the wg command is here, only a few bytes of data is exchanged and there is no internet access on the peer once they connect to the server.
❯ sudo wg
interface: utun4
  public key: <>
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 61820

peer: <>
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 192.168.1.254:45341
  allowed ips: 10.0.10.2/32
  latest handshake: 8 seconds ago
  transfer: 41.92 KiB received, 912 B sent

❯ ifconfig utun4
utun4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
    inet 10.0.10.1 --> 10.0.10.1 netmask 0xffffff00

❯ sudo /usr/sbin/networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 1.1.1.1

❯ cat /etc/resolv.conf
#
# macOS Notice
#
# This file is not consulted for DNS hostname resolution, address
# resolution, or the DNS query routing mechanism used by most
# processes on this system.
#
# To view the DNS configuration used by this system, use:
#   scutil --dns
#
# SEE ALSO
#   dns-sd(1), scutil(8)
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
search lan
nameserver 1.1.1.1

-- I'm able to connect to the internet from the server, with a SSH session
❯ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.217.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=0 ttl=119 time=14.757 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.217.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=14.312 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.312/14.534/14.757/0.223 ms

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate any pointers here. It feels like there is some problem with my firewall config, but I'm not very familiar with setting this up on a Mac.
I've also tried using a Docker container to setup wireguard and had the exact same problem and then moved onto bare-metal.
